# Opening files with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on a simple electron text editor, which is supposed to do basic CRUD operations.

I was able to read and write files using FS node module, and I can easily get the path to the file with electron dialogs. I want my user to be able to open a .txt file with the program, but not require him or her to launch the program first and then select the file.

Imagine you have a text file on your desktop, you set all .txts to be opened with myAmazingTextEditor, and so when you double click it it opens up the app and displays content of the file in a textarea.

Basically, my problem is handling the incoming files. How do I check if the app is being opened by a file?

Thanks a lot folks!

Comment: Did the file URL of incoming file passed through `argv`?

Comment: Usually, the OS passes the file path as the first command line argument, which should be available through `process.argv`.

Comment: @still_learning Interesting, I wasn't aware of `process.argv`, but thanks for bringing it to my attention. I'm diving into documentation as we speak :)

Comment: Did you guy any solution for this? if so, would you please share and accept your own answer, I'm struggling with the same :-\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was building an app with Electron. I managed to find a solution on [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/open-a-file-with-electron-app/41528) site:

In the main:

```
// read the file and send data to the render process
ipcMain.on('get-file-data', function(event) {
  var data = null
  if (process.platform == 'win32' && process.argv.length >= 2) {
    var openFilePath = process.argv[1]
    data = openFilePath
  }
  event.returnValue = data
})
```

And in the renderer:

```
var data = ipcRenderer.sendSync('get-file-data')
if (data ===  null) {
    console.log("There is no file")
} else {
    // Do something with the file.
    console.log(data)
}
```